# Apache or PHP keeps the HTML output in some kind of cache for a couple of minutes?

Tags: php, apache, caching

I recently ditched XAMPP on my Windows 10 machine and re-installed Apache (2.4), PHP 7 and MySQL manually (I followed the instructions [given here](https://www.dionysopoulos.me/233-apache-mysql-php-server-on-windows-with-multiple-simultaneous-php-versions.html) in order to be able to switch between PHP versions easily).

Everything works fine, except that now when I make a change in a PHP file and hit Refresh in the browser, the change often doesn't appear immediately in the browser. No matter how hard I hit F5 (or Ctrl+F5), I still get the non-modified source code, and I have to wait a couple of minutes before those change are finally visible to the browser.

Needless to say, it's quite annoying when developing. And it didn't happen when I was using XAMPP.

So there seems to be some kind of cache somewhere, but I can't find where it is. I don't know if it's Apache or PHP, although I suspect it might be PHP, because the CSS or JS files are not affected by this problem (as far as I can tell).

Any idea what's causing this behavior and how to disable it?

**EDIT:** I did some more testing.

I created the simplest PHP file possible. Just:

```
<?php
echo 'test1';
```

I can confirm that the problem occurs even in this simple case (changing "test1" to "test2": the browser still shows "test1" for a while).

Opening the same page in another browser still shows the outdated code (test1 instead of test2).

Clearing the browser cache doesn't help.

So the problem doesn't seem to happen on the client side.

*However*, if I do the same test with an HTML file instead of a PHP file, then the problem *doesn't occur*. Any change done to that file is visible immediately in the browser (of course I'm still accessing this file via Apache, so http://localhost/some-path/test.html)

So the problem seems to affect only PHP files.

Comment: First thing _always_ to check is if your _browser_ caches such content. So empty your browsers cache and retry. You can also open your browsers development console and disable the cache in there.

Comment: There are server side caching strategies, but those are not implemented in the http server or inside php. You'd have to take special steps to install such layer, you'd know if you did.

Comment: It's not the browser. I tried Ctrl+F5 and also emptying its cache. Opening the same page in another browser also shows the outdated page. Like I said, this behavior didn't happen when I was using XAMPP, so it really seems to be something happening server-side.

Comment: Then I suggest you start examining what actually happens inside your server. check the http servers log files: do the requests actually come in? What are the headers the responses carry, which you can easily check in your browsers console? Where do you actually keep those scripts you alter, is it a local drive or something "virtual"?

Comment: Checking the access log: all seems to be OK, every refresh in the browser generates a new entry in the form `"GET /my-path/test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 5`. The scripts are stored on my hard drive (`c:\htdocs`), nothing virtual. What should I look for in the response headers?

Comment: Note: I've updated my post with more information. The problem seems to affect PHP files exclusively (not HTML or CSS files)...

Comment: any opcache entries in your php.ini?

Comment: Yes: `opcache.enable=1` and a bunch of variants. I had to enable that for some work on Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org/node/2679959). Do you think it's what causes it?

Comment: Actually I wrote above: You'd have to take special steps to install such layer, you'd know if you did.... _Now_ you tell us you did...

Comment: Sorry about that. Like I said, I just followed some instruction in order to work on a Drupal project. It was weeks ago and I had no idea it would have this kind of effect.

Comment: Yes, it seems that was the cause of the problem. I'll post the answer below in case it helps somebody. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `No matter how hard I hit F5 (or Ctrl+F5), I still get the non-modified source code` have you tried a hammer?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem was caused by the OPCache module, which I [had to enable](https://www.drupal.org/node/2679959) in order to work on another (drupal 8) project.

In `php.ini`, the following line:

```
; How often (in seconds) to check file timestamps for changes to the shared
; memory storage allocation. ("1" means validate once per second, but only
; once per request. "0" means always validate)

opcache.revalidate_freq=60
```

Changing 60 to 1 (and restarting Apache) basically solved the problem.